# Excel - sum if name is subset of another

Tags: excel, subset, contains, sumifs

Say I have a table like this in Excel (except the third and last column, which is what I want to obtain)

| Name | Value | *What I want* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 1 |
| X-Y | 1 | 2 |
| X-Y-Z | 0 | 2 |
| X-V | 1 | 2 |

So in column 3 I want to do a sumif which sums the column "Value" across all rows where Name is a subset of the given name in the row being looked at.
E.g. for row 2 the returned value will be 2 - because both X and X-Y is a subset of X-Y - so it sums these two rows' values.

How can I do this in a formula?

Comment: What formula have you tried so far which didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.
In C2 put

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$5; --(IFERROR(IF(FIND($A$2:$A$5;A2)>0;1;0);0)=1))
```